# QT6+VTK9.1 on Windows build error: Undefined Reference to QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget

Tags: c++, vtk, undefined-reference, qtwidgets, qt6

I have installed QT6 and successfully build VTK 9.1. I have added the following environment variables:

```
%QTDIR%\bin
%QTDIR%\lib
%VTK_DIR%\bin
```

where `QTDIR` points to **C:\Qt\6.2.3\msvc2019_64** and `VTK_DIR` points to **C:\VTK** where the VTK is installed after build. The `VTK_DIR` contains bin, include, and lib directories.

In the **project.pro** file, I have added the following:

```
QT += core gui opengl
...
INCLUDEPATH += $$(VTK_DIR)/include/vtk-9.1
LIBS += -LC:$$(VTK_DIR)/lib
```

I don't get any missing header file errors which means that QT Creator finds the header files. The project runs fine in QT Creator without adding **OpenGL Widget** to the form. But when I add **OpenGL Widget** to the form, it gives the following error:

```
17:16:06: Running steps for project VTKTest...
17:16:06: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
17:16:06: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw900_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" -j12
C:/Qt/6.2.3/mingw_64/bin/qmake.exe -o Makefile ../VTKTest/VTKTest.pro -spec win32-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw900_64/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Work/Qt/Creator/build-VTKTest-Desktop_Qt_6_2_3_MinGW_64_bit-Debug'
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o debug/VTKTest.exe debug/main.o debug/mainwindow.o debug/moc_mainwindow.o  -LC:C:/VTK/lib C:/Qt/6.2.3/mingw_64/lib/libQt6OpenGL.a C:/Qt/6.2.3/mingw_64/lib/libQt6Widgets.a C:/Qt/6.2.3/mingw_64/lib/libQt6Gui.a C:/Qt/6.2.3/mingw_64/lib/libQt6Core.a -lmingw32 C:/Qt/6.2.3/mingw_64/lib/libQt6EntryPoint.a -lshell32  
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw900_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: debug/mainwindow.o: in function `Ui_MainWindow::setupUi(QMainWindow*)':
C:\Test\build-VTKTest-Desktop_Qt_6_2_3_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/./ui_mainwindow.h:33: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN22QVTKOpenGLStereoWidgetC1EP7QWidget6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Debug:72: debug/VTKTest.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Test/build-VTKTest-Desktop_Qt_6_2_3_MinGW_64_bit-Debug'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:45: debug] Error 2
17:16:12: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw900_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project VTKTest (kit: Desktop Qt 6.2.3 MinGW 64-bit)
When executing step "Make"
17:16:12: Elapsed time: 00:06.
```

I have also tried with `LIBS += $$(VTK_DIR)/lib` and `LIBS += $$(VTK_DIR)/lib/*.lib`, no joy.

In VS2019 I have installed the **QT VS Tools** which works fine. I also added all the VTK include, lib, and bin directories in project VC++ Directories section. Without adding **OpenGL Widget** to the form the project runs fine. But here too when I add **OpenGL Widget** to the form, it gives me the following build error:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: VTKTest, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Reading Qt configuration (C:/Qt/6.2.3/msvc2019_64/bin/qmake)
1>VTKTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget::QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget(class QWidget *,class QFlags<enum Qt::WindowType>)" (__imp_??0QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@V?$QFlags@W4WindowType@Qt@@@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl Ui_VTKTestClass::setupUi(class QMainWindow *)" (?setupUi@Ui_VTKTestClass@@QEAAXPEAVQMainWindow@@@Z)
1>VTKTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget::~QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget(void)" (__imp_??1QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __cdecl QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GQVTKOpenGLStereoWidget@@UEAAPEAXI@Z)
1>VTKTest.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
1>VTKTest.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget::paintEvent(class QPaintEvent *)" (?paintEvent@QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQPaintEvent@@@Z)
1>VTKTest.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
1>VTKTest.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z)
1>VTKTest.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget::resizeEvent(class QResizeEvent *)" (?resizeEvent@QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQResizeEvent@@@Z)
1>C:\Test\VTKTest\x64\Debug\VTKTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "VTKTest.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It seems that both QT Creator and VS2019 cannot find the runtime libraries (in this case `QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget`). I tried many posts, questions, videos, and tutorials but the issue is not resolving.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

LIBS should contain not only the path, but also the libraries you want to link. Haven't test my code on Windows/Qt6 yet, but on Linux/Qt5 all necessary VTK libraries are linked automatically when you specify to link libvtkGUISupportQt. So you could try something like this:

```
LIBS += $$(VTK_DIR)/lib -lvtkGUISupportQt
```

That worked for me.